# Mqtt protocol for windows phone

Tags: c#-3.0, mqtt

How to use the mqtt protocol in windows phone.I got code from mqtt site which is an .net application and i am able to run that app successfully,but when i am trying to incorporate the same thing in windows phone i got 3 errors.
1)hashtable is not recognized so i substituted dictonary<> 
2)tcpclient is not recognized...can anyone tell me some alternative 
3)networkstream is not recognized...

so please can anyone suggest me some alternative for tcpclient and networkstream.

Basically we want to implement push notification without help of mpns in windows phone.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that TCP sockets are now supported for Windows Phone 7 apps (since the Mango SDK update).

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202858(VS.92).aspx for a sample and tutorial.

Good luck!